# Conditional Probability of a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

A manufacturer produces bullets that follow a normal distribution $X\sim N(26.9,1.21^2)$. Given that a shooter is given 10 bullets that are between 25.3g and 28.8g, find the probability that at least 8 are between 26g and 29g.

I thought about using the formula for conditional probability where $A$ is the probability that at least 8 were between 26 and 29g while $B$ is the probability that all the 10 given were between 25.3 and 28.8g. Hence $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

So I would think $P(B)$ be binomial with number of trials 10 with probability being found using the normal distribution of $P(25.3<X<28.8)$ while the numerator would be using a binomial distribution and find sum the probability of getting 8,9 or 10 successes while the probability of success would be found using the normal distribution of $P(26<X<28.8)$. However, the numerator gives me a number larger than the denominator so one of the thought processes, or both, must be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would calculate the probability of getting one between $26$ and $28.8$ given it is between $25.3$ and $28.8$ because that's a straightforward ratio $P(26<X<28.8)/P(25.3<X<28.8)$ with respect to the normal distribution.  Then use that number as $p$ in a binomial with $n=10$ and calculate $P(n\geq 8)$ with respect to that binomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would calculate the probability of getting one between $26$ and $28.8$ given it is between $25.3$ and $28.8$ because that's a straightforward ratio $P(26<X<28.8)/P(25.3<X<28.8)$ with respect to the normal distribution.  Then use that number as $p$ in a binomial with $n=10$ and calculate $P(n\geq 8)$ with respect to that binomial.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the weight of an individual bullet. If we are told that the bullets are between $25.3$g and $28.8$g then
  $$p =  P(26 < W < 20 \, | \, 25.3 < W < 28.8 ) = \frac{ P(26 < W < 28.8) }{ P(25.3 < W < 28.8) } $$
Because the interval in the numerator is contained within the interval in the denominator, the fraction must work out to be smaller than $1$.

Now, you may use the binomial distribution with $10$ trials and $p$ given by the above.